# Business visa to Bangladesh for a Canadian citizen residing in the UK

Tags: visas, uk, canada, business-travel, bangladesh

Here's the situation:

- Canadian citizen, residing in the UK, working remotely for a Canadian business
- As part of that work, needs to visit Bangladesh on a business trip
- Would like to apply for the Bangladesh visa from the UK where he lives

I've checked the website of the [Bangladesh High Commission in London](http://www.bhclondon.org.uk/Visa.html#bv). It seems that they do issue visas for Canadians, but for a business visa they require "*A letter from concern business organization **in the UK** introducing the applicant, his employment status in the organization and the purpose of visit to Bangladesh*"

Unfortunately the person described can't produce a letter from an organization in the UK, since his employer is in Canada. Will the Bangladesh High Commission in London accept a letter from a Canadian organization instead?

Comment: Is the prospective traveler authorized to work in the UK and paying taxes there, etc.?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know, asking for a friend of a friend, but I'm 99.9% sure everything is legitimate (all necessary authorizations, taxes paid if they need to be paid, etc). Would something like this be relevant to the Bangladeshi consulate?

Comment: Possibly. The Schengen rules require applicants to be legally present where they are applying. Bangladesh could have a similar requirement that business applicants be working legally where they are applying. You might geta better response at http://expatriates.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

Canadian citizens are allowed to enter Bangladesh for tourism or business purposes, receiving a **visa on arrival**. No documents need to be produced at the border. The maximum length of stay is 30 days.

Therefore your friend doesn't need to apply for a visa at the consulate.

Source: [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=BD&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=00&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C).

Comment: Thanks - I missed this possibility. However, the info seems confusing.  I checked the database at http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ and it doesn't mention a visa-on-arrival possibility. The Bangladeshi government site ( http://visitbangladesh.gov.bd/visa-on-arrival/ ) is even more confusing, point (a) seems to conflict point (c), and point (c) talks about the country you're arriving from, not the country of citizenship or residence, which makes very little sense. WikiVoyage ( https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bangladesh ) has conflicting info on VOA in the general and Canada-specific sections.

Comment: @EugeneO The Bangladeshi government site is pretty straightforward if you only realize each of the conditions is separate — as long as you satisfy one, you don't need to satisfy the others. And there's a clear conditions about Canadian citizens allowed on VOA without extra docs.